# JQuery mobile adds form element after calling a async function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm using jquery mobile. In my form I have two selectmenu filterable plugin. After I push the button (not submitting the page, only calling a javascript async function that sends parameters to server), the structure of the page is not the same as before. The filter textboxes are shown below each "select" method, and nothing works! I expanded the elements of the page, and I saw that it automatically wraps  element with  tag (after the function ends). So maybe that's why the structure is disassembled. Any idea how to fix this problem?

UPDATE:

This is the code for html (other codes are originally from jQuery):

```
<div class="ui-field-contain"> 
    <select id="lstProjects" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select">
         <option>Select Project</option> 
    </select> 
</div> 
<div class="ui-field-contain"> 
    <select id="lstDuration" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select"> 
        <option>Select Duration</option> 
    </select> 
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us the markup/css/script and also (if possible) reproduce the problem in a jsFiddle.

Comment: this is the code for html:
other codes are oroginally from jQuery.
<div class="ui-field-contain">
                <select id="lstProjects" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select">
                    <option>Select Project</option>

                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-field-contain">
                <select id="lstDuration" data-native-menu="false" class="filterable-select">
                    <option>Select Duration</option>
                </select>
            </div>